# Fill DropDownList with jquery and json ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have this code in my view :

```
<script>
    var isChanged = false;
    $(function () {
        $('#stageOne').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Shop/ChangeStageTwo/",
                    data: { item: $("#stageOne option:selected").text() },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (myJSONdata) {
                        $("#stageTwo").html("");      
                        var items = myJSONdata;
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            var item = items[i];
                            var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.text + '">' + items[i] + '</option>';
                            $("#stageTwo").append(optionhtml);
                        }
                 }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my ChangeStageTwo function :

```
    public JsonResult ChangeStageTwo(string item)
    {
        // Do something...          

        var query = from f in db.Stages
                    where f.Code.Contains(tempDelivCod) && f.Code.Length > 4
                    select f.Name;
        var sItems = new SelectList(query);
        return Json(sItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

But at run time I get [object Object] in my DropDownList, not the exact value. what is the problem?

Comment: Could you add a typical JSON example please?

Comment: Json data is a string list like this "aa","bb",...   now iget undefined error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function will works :

```
var items = myJSONdata;//somethink like ["aa", "bb"]...
$(items).each(function(index, optionText) {
    $("#stageTwo").append($('<option />').attr('value', optionText).text(optionText));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.text + '">' + items[i] + '</option>';
```

should be something like:

```
var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.text + '">' + item.text + '</option>';
```

or

```
var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.text + '</option>';
```

If you provide your JSON output, I can be more specific.